# Keep getting 404 on some URLs

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Having followed the guide to setup django, postgres and nginx in digitalocean, am get different results for different urls.
Am using ubuntu 20 and python 3.10

```
<IP>:8000 => is working perfectly well
<IP> => 404 Not Found
<https://DomainName> => Showing the html page but Not showing the static files
<https://www.DomainName> => 404 Not Found
```

Where am I messing up??

Comment: Well you need to always specify a port which is why :8000 works and nothing doesn't. If you want to use only IP you have to use web standards and use the default 443 port for https and 80 for http.

Comment: Also knowing how you stetted up the domain name as well as nginx and load balancing if any would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. All the URLs are now working perfectly.

Comment: If you dont mind checking the answer I posted so people know its fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you use web standards which ports are 443 for https and 80 for http you need to manually specify the port your service is located.